# Is it redundant to say "remove the presence of X" instead of "remove X"?

Tags: redundancy

I sometimes come across "remove the presence of", e.g. "remove the presence of these compounds". You can try a Google search for the exact phrase "remove the presence of" (with quotes) and you can see for yourself. It seems to be used in reference to chemical substances.

It seems redundant. Is this proper? Does in mean anything different than simply "remove X"? Or, maybe it's just a chemist's way of saying things?

Comment: I can't see any meaningful difference between "remove X" and "remove the presence of X."  I've also found the phrase in Christian theology.  Seems likely that these chemists and theologians are repeating what they've read.

Comment: In an experiment where the presence of X had an undesired effect it is logical to want to eliminate the presence of X. Using that wording keeps it symmetric.

Comment: Would you consider blood stains to be the "presence" of someone, even though the person themself is not actually present?

Answer (score -2):

*Remove* infers *the presence of*, such that *Remove the presence of X* adds no information to *Remove X*.  Redundant, verbose—take your pick.